# CMake does not set variables for g2o

Tags: c++, cmake

On macOS 11.0, I downloaded and built g2o (https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o) and installed it using `cmake --install .`
I then tried to include it in my own project via CMake like this (CMakeLists.txt):

```cpp
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.14)
project (MY-PROJECT)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# PkgConfig to find other packages easily
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED) 

# find required modules
pkg_check_modules(OpenCV REQUIRED opencv4)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(G2O REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "G2O FOUND: ")
message(STATUS ${G2O_FOUND}) # prints 1

message(STATUS "G2O INCLUDE DIRS: ")
message(STATUS ${G2O_INCLUDE_DIRS}) # prints nothing

message(STATUS "G2O Link Libraries: ")
message(STATUS ${G2O_LINK_LIBRARIES}) # prints nothing

message(STATUS "EIGEN3 INCLUDE DIRS: ")
message(STATUS ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS}) # prints /usr/local/include/eigen3
```

CMake sets `G2O_FOUND` to 1, indicating that it successfully found g2o. However, the other two variables are not set, so the include- and library-files are not found. I solved this by adding

```cpp
set(G2O_INCLUDE_DIRS
/usr/local/include)

set(G2O_LIBS
/usr/local/lib/libg2o_core.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libg2o_types_slam3d.dylib
#...
)

include_directories(
G2O_INCLUDE_DIRS  
)

target_link_libraries(
    MY-PROJECT
    ${G2O_LIBS}
)
```

to CMakeLists.txt, but I am still curious why CMake did find g2o but not set the variables accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why CMake did find g2o but not set the variables accordingly.

[FindG2O.cmake](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/blob/master/cmake_modules/FindG2O.cmake) does not set these variables, so they are not set. The variables checked for `G2O_FOUND` to be set are `G2O_STUFF_LIBRARY AND G2O_CORE_LIBRARY AND G2O_INCLUDE_DIR AND G2O_SOLVERS_FOUND`.

There is no rule that `find_package` has to set `_LIBRARIES` or `_INCLUDE_DIRS` variables - every package is a little different, consult that particular package. If writing `FindXXX` file, use interface or imported libraries instead of variables.

Comment: As all packages I used so far set these variables, I just assumed setting these to the correct values was the whole purpose of using `find_package()`, so the correct paths are found on different systems. I also did not know that the variables are set in the FindXXX-file, so next time I'll look there.

Comment: In my case, `G2O_FOUND` is set to 1. But Others `G2O_STUFF_LIBRARY` 
 AND `G2O_CORE_LIBRARY` AND `G2O_INCLUDE_DIR` AND `G2O_SOLVERS_FOUND` are not set